# Google Maps not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I have a function that gives the user directions from their location to a fixed location on a map. It is being loaded in as external content to populate a main div, the map shows fine on both IE and Firefox but when I view it in Chrome it does not show. The Chrome dev console shows that the content is being loaded into the div and it is not putting out any errors.

External map.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/location.js"></script>
<div id="mapContainer"></div>
<div id="writtenDir"></div>
```

JS to load content:

```
  $('#Contact').click(function () {
    $('#centerPane').load('External/map.html');
    $.getScript("JS/location.js");
  });
```

Location.js

```
if (navigator.geolocation) { 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoInfo, noGeoInfo);
} else {
  noGeoInfo();
}

function geoInfo(position) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) { 
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                    
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                 
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {  
      zoom: 15,        
      center: coords, 
      mapTypeControl: true, 
      navigationControlOptions:
      {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL 
      },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions); 
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById(''));
    var request = {
      origin: coords, 
      destination: '54.861283, -6.326805', 
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING 
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  });
}

function noGeoInfo() { 
  var location = new google.maps.LatLng(54.861283, -6.326805); 
  var mapOptions = { 
    center: location, 
    zoom: 15, //Sets zoom level (0-21)
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
    position: location, 
    map: map 
  });
}
```

Div to be loaded into:

```
<div id="centerPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
```

Why is the map not showing in Google Chrome?
(live link, press "Contact Us" - http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00518833/DNA/View/index.php)

Comment: "...  It is being loaded ...". I can guess what "it" is but could be wrong. Could you be explicit please.

Comment: The map is not visible.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @Johan Could you specify what other information you want? I've given the relevant code and pasted the link in case any one wished to view the site themselves to get a clearer picture of what I am describing.

Comment: Presumably the `<div id="centrePane" data-dojo-type=...>` gets transformed into `<div id="mapContainer"></div>`. What happens if you hard code the latter directly on the page?

Comment: `<div id="centrePane" data-dojo-type=...>` does not get transformed `<div id="mapContainer"></div>` is inserted into the `centrePane` div.

Comment: I can only assume that, in Chrome, the transformation happens too late, such that the Google Maps directive tries to establish a map in a non-existent div. Can you delay initialization of the map?

Comment: Sorry, the *insertion*, not transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resides inside the Nav.js file at line 59:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

The `map` is undefined when this line is executed.

Ensure that your js files are loaded in the right order and that the map is always defined before triggering the resize event.

[image]

I hope this helps.